# predicting a numerical value using KNN in weka

Tags: weka

I have two data sets, one for training and one for testing.
I am going to predict the values of a column with numerical type in test data set. In order to predict the value of an instance, I have to find the k nearest neighbors of that instance in training data set, and calculate the average of values. (waiting also can be used).

For example:

### column0 column1 column2

**......a..................b....................10**
**......a..................b....................12**
**......c..................d....................16**

**......a..................b....................?**

I need a method of data mining to give me the result = (10+12)/2 = 11
Which method should I use to get such a result? 
And do you know any good document which explains how to use that method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**KNN in Weka is implemented as IBk.  It is capable of predicting numerical and nominal values.**

If you are using the Weka Explorer (GUI) you can find it by looking for the "Choose" button under the Classify tab.  Once there navigate the folders:

classifiers -> lazy -> IBk

Once you select IBk, click on the box immediately to the right of the button.  This will open up a large number of options.  If you then click on the button "More" in the options window, you will see all of the options explained.  If you need more of an explanation of the classifier they even list the academic paper that the classifier is based on.  You can do this for all of the classifiers to obtain additional information.

Comment: I used IBK to solve the problem but I got this error : "Attribute isn't nominal, string or date!"

Comment: If you save your dataset as a ".arff" and open it in a simple text editor you may get some hint by looking at the header of the file.  Without a sample of the dataset you are using its hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: What is the method in IBK that gives me the predicted value that I marked it with "?" in the question? I used "double c = knn.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));" . I tested whether "c" is what I need, it is correct for 20 nearest neighbor but as I tested it for 100 nearest neighbor, I got the result 80.52 calculating by hand , while the code gave me 73.68. Why they are not the same? Do I use the wrong method?